# Using git behind a firewall

Tags: git, proxy, firewall

My lab is based in a hospital and we have quite a nasty firewall on our PCs.
I'm using git bash on a Win10 machine in combination with bitbucket.

I had to tweak the `.gitconfig` file a bit to bypass the firewall but it works fine.
Here's what got it to work for me:

```
#set http_proxy=http://username:password@[proxyhere]:8080
#set https_proxy=https://username:password@[proxyhere]:8080

#bitbucket.org[http "https://bitbucket.org"] proxy = http://[proxyhere]:8080
```

But, if I want to clone repos from github I fail... Adding

```
#github.com[http "https://github.com"] proxy = http://[proxyhere]:8080
```

Doesn't work. I keep getting the error :  "Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused"

I have to admit that I do not fully understand the way proxies are handled in win10 and git.
I tried various different things already that can be found in other threads like changing the SSL verification to false or swapping the proxy with the IP adress of my machine. But so far nothing worked.

Has anybody an idea what I have to change?

Best,
Niklas

Comment: Do you actually have `#` at the start of all those lines or it's just a copy-paste issue?

Comment: I actually have it at the beginning. It's not a copy paste issue

Comment: `#` at the beginning of the line is a comment and that line is ignored by `git`.

Comment: Sorry Paul, this is how the line looks in my .gitconfig file. Not the command typed into git bash... Maybe I should've stated that more clearly

Comment: Git ignores lines in `.gitconfig` that start with `#`.

Comment: This is interesting, cause if I delete those lines i cannot clone any repository... So your suggestion would be to remove the #?

Comment: According to `git help config` any line that starts with `#` (or `;`) is a comment and is ignored. Removing commented lines should not affect Git behaviour in any way. Ok, another idea - is it possible that line `#bitbucket.org[http "https://bitbucket.org"] proxy = http://[proxyhere]:8080` is actually 3 lines in your `.gitconfig` - `#bitbucket.org`, `[http ...]` and `proxy=` that got squashed when you posted them here?

Comment: No,
i just checked. It really is a single line. Just as displayed as above...

Comment: If I add a new line `[http "https://github.com"] proxy = http://[proxyhere]:8080`

the error message changes to :" Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT"

Comment: 407 is "Proxy Authentication Required". Try adding username:password to the url.